# Change positions of form array

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-material

I have a table where I show information from a form, and I have a button that adds a record, but when I generate the new element it takes the last position and I want it to take position 0 I tried using the splice function, but it didn't work, when I refresh the data source the positions still being the same before the splice

```
my form array
  myformArray = new FormArray([
    this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [0, Validators.required],
      empleado: ["Juan Antonio Vazquez", Validators.required],
      nss: ["ass5495d", Validators.required],
      capacitacion: ["SI", [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
    })
  ])
```

the adding the new record

```
  addRow() {
    let a =
      this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [1, Validators.required],
        empleado: ['', Validators.required],
        nss: ["", Validators.required],
        capacitacion: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
      })
    this.myformArray.push(a);
    let fromIndex = this.myformArray.value.indexOf(a.value);
    let toIndex = 0;
    let element = this.myformArray.value.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0];
 

    this.myformArray.value.splice(toIndex, 0, element);

    this.dataSource.data = this.myformArray.controls

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from **Materials cdkDrag** you can use the `moveItemInArray` function. Look the code [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-utils.ts).

*Here is the function itself:*

```
export function moveItemInArray<T = any>(array: T[], fromIndex: number, toIndex: number): void {
  const from = clamp(fromIndex, array.length - 1);
  const to = clamp(toIndex, array.length - 1);

  if (from === to) {
    return;
  }

  const target = array[from];
  const delta = to < from ? -1 : 1;

  for (let i = from; i !== to; i += delta) {
    array[i] = array[i + delta];
  }

  array[to] = target;
}
```

Call it simple like `moveItemInArray(this.myformArray, 0, 2)`. Have fun!

### Note

The `clamp` function helps with a min/max value. So you cannot have a highter `to` param as the array.length is.

```
function clamp(value: number, max: number): number {
  return Math.max(0, Math.min(max, value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but if you want to insert an item **at the beginning** of an array, you can use the [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this not works for me, since I recive an error that says that unshift is not part of fornArray

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it, I was changing the position of the form array value but I needed to change the position of the control instead

```
  addRow() {
    let a =
      this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [1, Validators.required],
        empleado: ['', Validators.required],
        nss: ["", Validators.required],
        capacitacion: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
      })
    this.myformArray.push(a);
    let fromIndex = this.myformArray.controls.indexOf(a);
    let toIndex = 0;
    let element = this.myformArray.controls.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0];


    this.myformArray.controls.splice(toIndex, 0, element);

    this.dataSource.data = this.myformArray.controls
  }
```